# Why can't pattern attribute and formControl be used for the same email field?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I do have an e-mail field and I use the attribute `pattern` for the RegEx check.

```
<input matInput formControlName="email" name="email" pattern="^\w+([d\\+1\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" #inputMail>
```

The browser behaves in a way strange if the email is too long e.g. firstNamelastNameWhatEverAsEmail@gmail.com

In other words, the browser freezes and hangs.. nothing is happening. I can't even close the browser - chrome in this case.

If I remove the attribute `pattern` or `formControlName`, then it works straight forward and I can type an e-mail as long as I can. So this means that I can't use them both at the same time.

Here is the formControl in the `***.component.ts**`:

```
 .....
 public form: FormGroup;
 .....
 this.form = this.fb.group({
     account: this.fb.group(
         {
             email: ['', Validators.required],
             xxxxx: ['', Validators.required],
             yyyyy: ['', Validators.required],
             zzzzz: ['', Validators.requiredTrue]
         }
     )
 });
```

Any idea?

Comment: This seems like a very valid issue... so it would be nice to know why people are voting it down. (I am very much in favor of banning the down vote!)

Comment: @DeborahK: That's true. Some user needs to vote down to get more privileges ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using reactive forms (as shown in your component code), you should not mix it with template-driven forms.

That basically means that you should not be mixing validation in the template (with the pattern attribute) and instead add all of your validation to the component.

```
Validators.pattern('yourpatternhere');
```

Here is one of mine for example:

```
this.fb.group({
    email: ['', [
                  Validators.required, 
                  Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+')
                ]
           ],
    xxxx: ''
});
```

NOTE: This was a *very* elementary example and is **not** meant to illustrate a valid email pattern.

Comment: This is working, but I still need to keep the attribute `pattern` in the view as I do have a error tag `<mat-error align="end" class="wrapper-mat-error">Error Message for the e-mail</mat-error>` for the input which shows up if email isn't valid. Without the `pattern` attribute, the error stays visible and I can't submit the form.

Comment: I have not tried material design with my reactive forms, but you can check out this post for an example of how to use mat-error without needing attributes: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-material-design-components-with-reactive-form-part-2/

Comment: Great! I'll check.